# Understanding the derivation of photon noise from Bose-Einstein statistics

Tags: optics, statistical-mechanics, photons, bosons, photon-emission

I will premise this question with the fact that I am trained in mathematics and not physics.

Right now I am reading Chapter 1 of the book [Optical Radiation Detectors](https://books.google.com/books/about/Optical_radiation_detectors.html?id=bjBRAAAAMAAJ) about radiation noise in blackbody sources. The author's state:

> The Bose-Einstein expression for the probability that the total photon energy at a specified frequency $\nu$ has a value $u$ is
> $$
> P(u)=\frac{e^{-u/kT}}{\int_0^\infty e^{-u/kT}\,\mathrm du}.
> $$
> The expected energy level (most probable value of $u$) is
> $$
> \bar u=\frac{\int_0^\infty u e^{-u/kT}\,\mathrm du}{\int_0^\infty e^{-u/kT}\,\mathrm du}=\frac{h\nu e^{-h\nu/kT}}{1-e^{-h\nu/kT}}.
> $$
> The expected number of photons, each of energy $h\nu$, must be
> $$
> \bar n=\frac{\bar u}{h\nu}=\frac{e^{-h\nu/kT}}{1-e^{-h\nu/kT}}
> $$

The author then goes on to derive similar expressions for $\bar n^2$ which leads to the following expression for the variance of photons emitted by a blackbody source:
$$
\sigma^2=\bar n\left[\frac{e^{h\nu/kT}}{e^{h\nu/kT}-1}\right],
$$
where the quantity in square brackets is referred to as the "boson factor".

I am struggling to follow the author's line of reasoning here. First, $P(u)$ appears to be defined as a continuous probability density due to the normalization constant being defined as an integral. However, if you interpret $P$ in this manner the expression for $\bar u$ is nonsensical. That said, what is meant by $\mathrm du$ in the above integrals? I am willing to accept that if $\mathrm du=\mathrm d\mu$ is a counting measure then
$$
\frac{\int_0^\infty ue^{-u/kT}\,\mathrm d\mu}{\int_0^\infty e^{-u/kT}\,\mathrm d\mu}=\frac{\sum_{u=0}^\infty ue^{-u/kT}}{\sum_{u=0}^\infty e^{-u/kT}}=\frac{e^{-1/kT}}{1-e^{-1/kT}},
$$
which looks similar to the expression for $\bar n$. That said, it is completely unclear to me where the factor of $h\nu$ in the expressions for $\bar u$ and $\bar n$ come from. I understand that $h\nu$ is the energy of a photon with frequency $\nu$; however, from a mathematical perspective I am not seeing how it ends up in $\bar u$ and $\bar n$.  Could someone please walk me through: $(1)$ where does the expression for $P(u)$ come from, and $(2)$ how we derive the expressions for $\bar u$ and $\bar n$?

Comment: A red flag popped up when the author refers to $P(u)$ as probability.  As you surmise, it is a probability density.  That kind of thing puts me off immediately.  I start to think I should find another book.  The next thing that strikes me is that his distribution looks like the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution, not  B-E, but I may be reading too quickly.  I should check his math now, but I won't.  Given $P(u)$ is a probability density, then his expression is the usual definition of an average.

Comment: Your last expression:  the first two expressions have units of energy, the last is dimensionless. But it has another problem in that the argument of the exponential *does* have units.  It shouldn't.   I think you need to take a step back.   And find another book.  I can't think of one to recommend, but get a standard.  Check the number of reviews the book has, that gives some idea of the books value.  "Counting measure"?  Wouldn't it be great if physicists knew more math?

Comment: @garyp For what its worth I found another [source](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1708/1708.09524.pdf) confirming that we should be evaluating $\bar n$ and $\sigma^2$ with sums not integrals. Equation (32) is the same expression as $\sigma^2$ in my post.  If anyone can give me the layman's explanation of what eq. (32) in this paper is and the gist of how its derived that would be enough to answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From statistical physics, if a system is in contact with a "reservoir" of heat and particles, then the energy of the system $E$ and the particle number $N$ are allowed to fluctuate.

If the set of microstates of the system form a discrete set (which would be the case for a system of particles which can inhabit discrete energy levels), then the probability that we find the system in a configuration $i$ with energy $E_i$ and particle number $N_i$ is proportional to $\exp[-\beta(E_i - \mu N_i)]$, where $\beta = 1/kT$ and $\mu$ are the inverse temperature and chemical potential of the reservoir, respectively.  The actual probability can be determined by normalizing; defining the partition function

$$Z(\beta)=\sum_{\text{microstates}}e^{-\beta(E_i-\mu N_i)}$$

it follows that the probability of finding the system in microstate $i$ with energy $E_i$ and particle number $N_i$ is given by

$$\operatorname{Prob}(E_i,N_i) = e^{-\beta(E_i-\mu N_i)}/Z(\beta) $$

---

Now we specialize to your situation.  The trick is to let our system consist of a **single energy level** which photons could occupy.  Therefore, a microstate of our system is completely specified by writing down the number of photons which are present.  If the energy of our chosen level is given by $h\nu$, then if there are $N$ photons in our system the total energy will be $E =Nh\nu$.  We must also use the fact that the chemical potential of a photon gas is equal to $0$.

With that in mind, the partition function becomes
$$Z(\beta) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-\beta n h \nu}= \frac{1}{1-e^{-\beta h\nu}}$$
and the probability that there are $N$ photons in our system (which is equivalent to the probability that the system has total energy $Nh\nu$) is
$$P(N) = e^{-\beta Nh\nu}/Z(\beta)$$

From this you can calculate the expected number of photons present as $$\langle N \rangle = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n P(n) = -\frac{1}{h \nu} \frac{d}{d \beta}\log\big(Z(\beta)\big)$$
and the expected energy $\langle E\rangle = \langle N\rangle h\nu$, which should give you the results you're looking for.

---

At high temperatures (so $\beta$ is small), the sum in $Z(\beta)$ can be approximated by an integral, $Z(\beta) \approx \frac{1}{h\nu}\int_0^\infty e^{-\beta \epsilon}d\epsilon$, with the result being that $Z(\beta) \approx 1/\beta h \nu$ (you can see that this agrees with our calculation to first order in $\beta$).  This is the approximation being made by your authors.

The reason that you are (rightfully) confused may be that they first make an approximation by using an integral rather than a discrete sum, but **then** they give an expression which is **not** an approximation:

$$\bar u= \underbrace{\frac{\int_0^\infty u e^{-u/kT}\,\mathrm du}{\int_0^\infty e^{-u/kT}\,\mathrm du}}_{\text{Approximate}}=\underbrace{\frac{h\nu e^{-h\nu/kT}}{1-e^{-h\nu/kT}}}_{\text{Not approximate!}}$$

In the limit of large $T$, these expressions will agree with one another, but the tally of sins committed in such a short length of time would motivate me personally to find a new resource to learn from.